# How I can get ConcurrentModificationException while iterating Hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashmap

I am trying to add a key value pair to the hashmap inside the Iterator method.

But this is not giving me `ConcurrentModificationException` . Why?

Since Hashmap is failfast.

```
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
           m.put("a", "a");

           Iterator<String> i = m.keySet().iterator();
           while(i.hasNext()){
               System.out.println(i.next());
               m.put("dsad", "asfsdf");

           }
```

If this is wrong, How i can produce ConcurrentModificationException  ?
Thanks.

Update: Just checked.

```
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
               m.put("a", "a");
          m.put("abc", "a");

               Iterator<String> i = m.keySet().iterator();
               while(i.hasNext()){
                   System.out.println(i.next());
                   m.put("dsad", "asfsdf");

               }
```

This is giving me the exception.

Comment: Your problem is calling `m.put` while iterating over the map.  Should `i` go to the key `dsad`, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens that the concurrent modification check done by the `HashMap` code fails to detect this situation. The code for `HashMap`'s iterator's `hasNext` in Oracle's JDK7 is:

```
public final boolean hasNext() {
    return next != null;
}
```

...where (confusingly!) that `next` is a private data member in the iterator class (not to be confused with the `next` method on the `Iterator` interface — to my mind, calling that data member `next` was a *very* poor choice).

Note that it doesn't do the check for concurrent modifications. Contrast with this code that is called (indirectly) from `Iterator#next`:

```
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

...which *does* do the check.

So here's what happens in your code:

1. You create a `HashMap`.
2. You add one entry to it.
3. You begin an iteration.
4. `hasNext` is true, so you go into the body of your loop.
5. You get the element from `next`; at this point, the iterator remembers what the next element should be on its internal data member (the confusingly-named `next`), and in this case since there's no next element in the map, that `next` data member is set to `null`, meaning that the iteration is complete.
6. You add to the map.
7. Your code calls `hasNext`, which sees the `next` data member is `null` and returns `false`.

If you had two elements in the map before starting your loop instead of one, you'd get the exception (from `next`).

I've previously argued this is, or is very nearly, a bug, but it's a pretty fuzzy area, and others have argued quite reasonably that it isn't. The documentation doesn't say specifically which methods of `Iterator<E>` will throw the exception, just that it will get thrown. The documentation also says it's only thrown on a "best effort" basis, it's not guaranteed.

Whether one considers this a bug or not, it's unlikely to be changed at this point, as the pain of changing it (breaking some existing code that probably shouldn't have relied on this behavior) far outweighs the benefit (possibly being more "correct").

Comment: Why this is not a bug?

Comment: @Raj: Well, **I** think it *is* a bug. I've update the answer with some of the reasoning, and a deeper explanation of what's happening in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator may throw ConcurrentModificationException but is not guaranteed to.

From the javadoc of HashMap:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("a", "a");

    Iterator<String> i = m.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        m.remove("a");
        System.out.println(i.next());


    }
```